# Limiting Distribution $\Delta-$method

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $Y_n\sim \chi^2(n)$. What is the limiting distribution of $U_n= \dfrac{\sqrt{Y_n}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2}}?$.

What I know is that if $X_i\sim \chi^2(1)$, I can write $Y_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then the Central Limit Theorem implies that 
$$\dfrac{Y_n-n}{\sqrt{2n}/\sqrt{n}}=\dfrac{Y_n-n}{\sqrt{2}} \dot{\sim} N(0,1).$$
This is close to the form required for $U_n$ but not exact. I'm having trouble seeing how to make them fit. I also know, by the $\Delta-$method theorem that $$\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{Y_n}-\sqrt{n})\overset{d}\to N(0,\sigma^2g'(\mu)^2),$$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $Y_n-n$ and $g(t) = \sqrt{t}$. I guess I need help connecting these pieces to determine conclusively what $U_n$ has as its limiting distribution.

Answer (score 0):

An answer with hidden text, in case you want to try it out again before looking at the solution.

Using your definition of $Y_n$, you should have used the central limit theorem to observe
$$
\sqrt{n}(Y_n/n - 1)\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}N(0,2)\tag{1}
$$

So, using the delta method, with the function $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ and $(1)$, gives

> $$\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{Y_n/n} - 1\right)=\sqrt{Y_n} - \sqrt{n}\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}N(0,1/2)$$

Therefore,

> $$\frac{\sqrt{Y_n} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2}}\stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow}N(0,1/4)$$

[move your mouse cursor over hidden text to view]